# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when disable SSL in all pages on Prestashop

Tags: ssl, https, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have disabled SSL in all pages at Prestashop and now there is this error (i do not enter https and it puts https):
[image]

I tried deleting htaccess and regenerating it, but it didn't work.

This is the Prestashop configuration:
[image]

Which is the solution?

EDIT: My configuration of SSL at Prestashop configuration tab
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in prestashop after configure with ssl, admin dashboard works. but public sites doesn't work anymore. because you have to enable SSL for front pages, using admin dashboard like bellow.

- Enable SSL - yes
- Enable SSL on all pages - yes

change your shop parameters like this
[refer the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf9et.png)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Prestashop, however the issue is that at the time being the site enforces the HTTPS. In fact, the non-HTTPS version redirects to the HTTPS, there may be other redirects (that are not enabled now as I can access the redirect target) that may have caused the loop.

```
➜  ~  curl -I http://runvaspain.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 24 Jan 2016 10:44:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Location: https://runvaspain.com/
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000;includeSubDomains
```

Moreover, it looks like the site is setting the [HSTS header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000;includeSubDomains
```

This header is ignored when served via HTTP, however I suppose this was also served via HTTPS, therefore your browser have probably saved the configuration and it's enforcing the HTTPS locally (given that's what the HSTS is about).

You'll have to manually remove the strict transport configuration for the domain in your browser. However, please note that any user that previously accessed your site will have such setting, therefore they will be forced to use HTTPS for the main site **and all subdomains** for 6 months (as this is the policy you previous set).

Also note that, since you previously sent that header, HTTPS will be enabled for the entire site (and also subdomains), it's not possible to enable it on a single page (at least for the users who visited it before). The best thing to do is to turn HTTPS on again for the entire site.

To solve the first issue (the redirect to HTTPS) you should contact the Prestashop service. However, please note it will be almost irrelevant if the HSTS header was previously sent.

Answer (score 2):

The http version of the website ( http://runvaspain.com ) send a 301 redirect to the https version.

The https version of the website ( https://runvaspain.com ) use the HSTS header with a max-age of 6 month

That's mean that **anyone who visited the website is forced to visit the HTTPS version**

It's a security feature added by HSTS.

You have two solutions:

- Reactivate the https version (It's my advice, as **https add a significant security to your visitors**)
- Redirect the https to http **AND** modify the HSTS header (probably in your apache configuration) to send a max-age of 0. **You MUST send it for at least 6 month, you can't just remove it!** Sending a max-age on 0 indicate to visitors who already visited the website to forget the HSTS settings. If you just remove it, those visitors will not be able to visits the webpage for the next six months !

Answer (score 1):

I think Chrome just cached the URL. Happens to me all the time during development.

Try

1. List item
2. Click **Menu** (three dots or whatever icon is it now in Chrome in the upper right corner)
3. Hover over **More tools** then **Developer tools**
4. Click **Network** tab
5. Click **Disable cache** checkbox

[image: Chrome Network Disable cache]